# how to rename files using command line

Tags: command-line, cmd

I want to rename 2 files "Data1.txt" to "Log1.rtf" and "Data2.txt" to "Log2.rtf"

I am currently using this code

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%I IN ("%~dp0*.txt") DO (
SET "ext=%%~xI"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
RENAME "%%I" "%%~nI!Log.rtf"
ENDLOCAL
)
```

But it give output "data1log.rtf" and "data2log.rtf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course:

RENAME "%%I" "%%~`n`I!Log.rtf"

But it give output `data1`log.rtf and `data2`log.rtf

btw. what do you try to achive with `setlocal delayedexpansion` and that single `!` ?

**EDIT**: if you insist in doing it with `for` (because perhaps, you have many files to rename):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
 set file=%%i
 set file=!file:Data=Log!
 set file=!file:.txt=.rtf!
 echo ren %%i !file!
)
```

the first `set` sets the variable `file` to the filename

the second one replaces `Data` with `Log`

the third one replaces  `.txt` with `.rtf`

then rename original filename (`%%i`) to the changed filename (`!file!`)

(the `echo` is there to just show the command on screen instead of really renaming files. Good for testing. If you are sure, that the code does, what you want, just remove the `echo`)

the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is needed to use a variable, that is changed inside a block (between `(` and `)`) inside the same block. Therefore you have to use the variable as `!var!` instead of `%var%`

Note: of course this code could be improved, but as a beginner: keep it as simple (and readable) as possible. For example, this code will replace `Data`, but not `data` or `DATA`, it will not handle spaces in filenames, ...

Comment: Actually I don't know this code's work :p I just copy this code from somewhere else

Comment: ok, for just two files there is no need to mess around with `for`, especially, if you don't know much about it. Just `ren data1.txt log1.rtf` `ren data2.txt log2.rtf`. A `for` construct would make sense, if there are more files to process.

Comment: Thanks its working So I don't need "for". what if I use "for" twice instead for your code will it cost performance?

Comment: uhmm - yes - in theory. In fact, for just the two files, its about a few milliseconds - you will not notice any difference. Batch is nothing about performance. Just try to keep it simple. If you know exactly the names of the sourcefiles and destinationfiles, there is no need to make it complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It might work better if you used separate code to rename each of the files, or does that defeat the object?
this website shows how to rename a file using command line:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/56013-file-folder-rename-command-prompt.html

Comment: Now I am using same code twice is it right to use that
`@ECHO OFF

FOR %%I IN ("%~dp0*.txt") DO (

"ext=%%~xI"

EnableDelayedExpansion

RENAME "%%I" "Log1.rtf"

ENDLOCAL

)


@ECHO OFF

FOR %%I IN ("%~dp0*.txt") DO (

SET "ext=%%~xI"

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

RENAME "%%I" "Log2.rtf"

ENDLOCAL

)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in ("%~dp0data*.txt"
) do for /f "delims=DdAaTt" %%b in ("%%~na"
) do echo ren "%%~fa" "log%%b.rtf"
```

It just iterates over the indicated list of files, and for each filename, uses the unnecesary characters as delimiters for an aditional for loop. That way only the number is left and used to rename the file.

Commands to rename are echoed to console. If output is correct, remove the `echo` command to rename the files.

Comment: Renaming data1.txt to Logdata1.rtf I want Log1.rtf same happening to data2.txt to Logdata2.rtf

Comment: @UzairAli, what i see when i run it is `ren "D:\test\data1.txt" "log1.rtf"` The `for /f` with the indicated characters as delims should not let pass any `dta` characters.

Answer (score 0):

### User `mv` command to rename files in windows (Using CLI)

As mentioned in above answer, `mv` command can be used in windows as well to rename the filename. I tried `rename` and `ren` commands s suggested, but I was getting error: `bash: ren: command not found.`

Use below to change the filename:
`mv filename new_filename`